# How to access a property in another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

I am working with a WPF .Net Core 3 project.

In my UnbalancedViewModel I need to access an ID from another class (TestRunDto.cs). 
[image]

**UnbalancedViewModel**

```
public class UnbalancedViewModel : ViewModelBase, IUnbalancedViewModel
{        
    private TestRunApi _testRunApi;

    public UnbalancedViewModel(TestRunApi testRunApi, INotificationManager notifications)
    {            
     _testRunApi = testRunApi; 
    }

    private void StartTestRunJobExecuted(object obj)
    {
        _testRunApi.StartTestRun(1); ////I need the Id from TestRunDto (TestRunDto.Id)
    }
}
```

**TestRunApi**

```
public async Task<TestRunLiveValueDto> GetTestRunLiveValue(int jobRunId)
{
    await using var dbContext = new AldebaDbContext(_connectionString);
    return await TestRunInteractor.GetTestRunLiveValue(jobRunId, dbContext);
}

public async Task StartTestRun(int testRunId)
{
    await using var dbContext = new AldebaDbContext(_connectionString);
    await TestRunInteractor.StartTestRun(dbContext, testRunId);
}
```

**TestRunLiveValueDto**

```
public class TestRunLiveValueDto
{
    public TestRunDto TestRun { get; }
    public bool ShowInstantaneousValue { get; set; }
    public bool EnableStart { get; set; }
    public bool EnableStop { get; set; }
    public bool EnableMeasure { get; set; }
    public int RecipeRpm { get; }
    public string ActualRecipeName { get; }
    public int DefaultSetOfPlaneId { get; }

    public ICollection<BalancePlaneDto> ListBalancePlane { get; }
    public ICollection<SetOfPlaneDto> ListSetOfPlane { get; }
    public ICollection<SensorVibrationDto> SensorVibrations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EstimationDto> InstantaneousValues { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EstimationDto> EstimationsValues { get; set; }

    private TestRunLiveValueDto(TestRunDto testRun, bool enableStart, bool enableStop, int recipeRpm,  ICollection<SensorVibrationDto> sensorVibrations)
    {
        EnableStart = enableStart;
        EnableStop = enableStop;
        TestRun = testRun;
        RecipeRpm = recipeRpm;
        SensorVibrations = sensorVibrations;
    }

    public static TestRunLiveValueDto Create(TestRunDto testRun, bool enableStart, bool enableStop, int recipeRpm, ICollection<SensorVibrationDto> sensorVibrations)
        => new TestRunLiveValueDto(testRun,  enableStart,  enableStop, recipeRpm, sensorVibrations);
}
```

**TestRunDto**

```
public class TestRunDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int JobRunId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TestRunNumber { get; set; }
    public RunState State { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BalancePlaneDto> BalancePlanes { get; set; } // Todo remove

    private TestRunDto(int id, int jobRunId, RunState state, string name, int testRunNumber)
    {
        Id = id;
        JobRunId = jobRunId;
        Name = name;
        TestRunNumber = testRunNumber;
        State = state;
    }

    public static TestRunDto Create(int id, int jobRunId, RunState state, string name, int testRunNumber)
        => new TestRunDto(id, jobRunId, state, name, testRunNumber);
}
```

I have been trying to understand this, but I can not get a hold of the proper method to do this. Do I first declare a new `TestRunDto` class in my viewmodel or am I supposed to access it some other way?

Comment: What calls `StartTestRunJobExecuted`?

Comment: It's called through a button click - StartTestRunJobCommand = New DelegateCommand(StartTestRunJobExecuted);

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure class A has a reference to an instance of class B to access the properties, for example one way of doing this is to pass class A to B in a method where you can manipulate or access properties.

```
public class FooA 
{
   public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class FooB 
{ 
   public string PropertyB { get; set; } 

   public void CanAccessFooA(FooA a) 
   { 
       a.PropertyA = "See, I can access this here";
   } 
}
```

Another is to pass class A to B in the constructor (known as dependency-injection)

```
public class FooB 
{ 
   FooA _a; 

   public FooB(FooA a) 
   { 
      // Pass instance of FooA to constructor 
      // (inject dependency) and store as a member variable
      this._a = a;
   } 

   public string PropertB { get; set; } 

   public void CanAccessFooA() 
   { 
       if (this._a != null)
          this._a.PropertyA = "See, I can access this here";
   } 
}
```

Exactly how to structure your code is up to you, but the principle remains the same: **Class B can only access Class A if it has a reference to an instance of it.**

Look into 'Dependency Injection' as there are many techniques to achieve this.

**Edit**

One such technique might be abstracting the code to provide the ID to both, like so

```
public class IdProvider 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
} 

public class FooA 
{
   private int _id; 
   public FooA(IdProvider idProvider) 
   {
      _id = idProvider.Id;
   }
} 

public class FooB
{
   private int _id; 
   public FooB(IdProvider idProvider) 
   {
      _id = idProvider.Id;
   }
}
```

Now both classes have the same ID;

Answer (score 0):

`StartTestRun` takes the `tesRunId` as it's parameter.

```
public async Task StartTestRun(int testRunId)
{
```

I think you need to call `StartTestRunJobExecuted` with this `testRunId`.

You will to change

```
private void StartTestRunJobExecuted(object obj)
```

to

```
private void StartTestRunJobExecuted(int testRunIdn)
{
   _testRunApi.StartTestRun(testRunId); ////I need the Id from TestRunDto (TestRunDto.Id)
}
```

(This based on me guessing).